# Can multiple people operate one account?

Tags: discussion, reputation, users, rules

I am wondering if it's fine for multiple people to use one account.

For example, you have 20 friends from your school who are good with 20 different programming languages. You created one account and gave them your Stack Overflow login information and they all login and answer questions based on their own programming language tag every day. Within few months, the account rep becomes extremely bigger than Jon Skeet's rep and with more than 20 gold tag badges.

- Does this break any Stack Overflow rule?
- If not, is this fair to other Stack Overflow users?

---

Note:

I do not do this. I am just curious.

Comment: Not to nitpick your question, but catching up to Jon Skeet is nigh on impossible unless you consistently get repcap and more then 10-15 accepts and/or large bounties daily for years.

Comment: Sounds like a good way for 20 people to get question-banned at once:)

Comment: @Magisch The John Skeet part was just a joke. I don't think that can ever happen even in 20 years let alone in "months".

Comment: related question on overmeta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82509 .

Comment: @Programmer Since Jon gets 200 rep every day regardless of accepts, excluding bounties, you would need to get almost 180 accepts every single day to catch him in less than a year. So, it's doable I guess... Ahem...

Comment: @DavidG In that case it it but still extremely complicated.

Comment: Try asking John to send 20 of his clones for your help. Its technically the same person you know. So its possible but its again up to him if he is willing to pass himself or not...

Comment: Excellent question! I'd never thought of that. It's the reverse we focus on.

Comment: Semi-related: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/148354/why-is-account-sharing-so-bad

Answer (score 48, accepted):

No, multiple people cannot legally operate a single account.

The [Stack Exchange Network Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) prohibit this. Accounts can only be operated by individuals, and they are *solely responsible* for all content submitted under that name.

> **1. Access to the Services**
>
> Subject to the terms and conditions of this Agreement, Stack Exchange may offer to provide the Services, as described more fully on the Network, and which are selected by Subscriber, solely for Subscriber’s own use, and not for the use or benefit of any third party. Services shall include, but not be limited to, any services Stack Exchange performs for Subscriber, as well as the offering of any Content (as defined below) on the Network. Stack Exchange may change, suspend or discontinue the Services at any time, including the availability of any feature, database, or Content. Stack Exchange may also impose limits on certain features and services or restrict Subscriber’s access to parts or all of the Services without notice or liability. Stack Exchange reserves the right, at its discretion, to modify these Terms of Service at any time by posting revised Terms of Service on the Network and by providing notice via e-mail, where possible, or on the Network. Subscriber shall be responsible for reviewing and becoming familiar with any such modifications. Use of the Services by Subscriber following such modification constitutes Subscriber's acceptance of the terms and conditions of this Agreement as modified.
>
> **Subscriber certifies to Stack Exchange that Subscriber is an individual (i.e., not a corporate entity) at least 13 years of age.** No one under the age of 13 may provide any personal information to or on Stack Exchange (including, for example, a name, address, telephone number or email address). Subscriber also certifies that they are legally permitted to use the Services and access the Network, and takes full responsibility for the selection and use of the Services and access of the Network. This Agreement is void where prohibited by law, and the right to access the Network is revoked in such jurisdictions. Stack Exchange makes no claim that the Network may be lawfully viewed or that Content may be downloaded outside of the United States. Access to the Content may not be legal by certain persons or in certain countries. If You access the Network from outside the United States, You do so at Your own risk and You are responsible for compliance with the laws of Your jurisdiction.

(Emphasis added.)

Further:

> **7. Registration and security**
>
> As a condition to using Services, Subscriber may be required to register with Stack Exchange and select a password and profile name. Subscriber shall provide Stack Exchange with accurate, complete, and updated registration information, including Subscriber’s e-mail address. Failure to do so shall constitute a breach of this Agreement, which may result in immediate termination of Subscriber's account. Subscriber may not (a) select or use as a profile name a name of another person with the intent to impersonate that person; or (b) use as a profile name a name subject to any rights of a person other than Subscriber without appropriate authorization. Stack Exchange reserves the right to refuse registration of, or cancel a profile name in its discretion. Subscriber shall be responsible for maintaining the confidentiality of Subscriber's  password. Subscriber is solely responsible for any use of or action taken under Subscriber’s password and accepts full responsibility for all activity conducted through Subscriber’s account and agrees to and hereby releases the Network and Stack Exchange from any and all liability concerning such activity. Subscriber agrees to notify Stack Exchange immediately of any actual or suspected loss, theft, or unauthorized use of Subscriber’s account or password. The Network will take reasonable security precautions when using the internet, telephone or other means to transport data or other communications, but expressly disclaims any and all liability for the accessing of any such data communications by unauthorized persons or entities.

Comment: That's exactly a main reason why account sharing is prohibited in, for instance, online games. Otherwise the laziest excuse called _"I haven't done that, he did"_  could've been valid :-) :-)

Comment: @Skipper It doesn't really matter in that case, the account gets banned either way, with or without the excuse

Comment: I find it disturbing this information isn't all that obvious. Sure its in the terms of service, but realistically, that is one of the largest wall of text on the site. The presence of such a question is proof not that many people read through that.

Comment: I asked about this once and was told that this is okay, but I don't believe it should be, and this confirms it. I believe that this information is not taken as seriously as it should be. I have my suspicions of some high ranked users having shared accounts, but this is something that cannot be proven, which is the biggest problem associated with this.

Comment: @PasserBy You act like most people read the terms of service of websites or software. Most don't and that shouldn't be "disturbing". It's just that there so many terms of services for anything you use these days to the extent that you would grow white hair by the time you're done reading all of them. I read the rules on this site and sometimes Google some of them I can't find specific  one. I don't think this question is bad like you made it seem.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It **can** actually be detected by checking if someone is typing an answer from multiple devices at the-same time,if there is different IP Address for different answers posted recently and within few minutes apart, posted long answer in a very short amount of time from 2 different IP Addresses. A combination of behaviors can be used to detect this. I am sure the team can put something more sophisticated to detect this if not already.

Comment: @Programmer Um.. you misunderstood. I meant the information isn't displayed prominently enough such that not all users know this _before_ registering. ToS are the worst written "manuals" out there (because they are'nt), look at Google Play Store for a far better way of displaying info

Comment: @PasserBy I think I did. I apologize for that.

Comment: @Andrew I phrased it as I did quite intentionally. This isn't really something in the TOS that we enforce unless you are causing a serious disruption on other grounds, so it really is mostly a legal issue. Which also answers the objections here of why it isn't made more visible. It doesn't need to be.

Comment: It isn't against the law to use an account with more than one person, so I don't think it is accurate to mention that it is "illegal". Also, your citation only addresses the owner of the account, the "subscriber", and not the actual use of the account - it just states that the subscriber is liable for any and all actions. While I am not advocating using an account with more than one person, nothing here really prevents that, except perhaps for the part stating SE will shut down an account for their any reason they want (multiple users being the reason).

Comment: @Travis In the United States, breaking the Terms of Service for a website *is* against the law, a violation of the Computer Fraud and Abuse Act (a federal law). Now, granted, it is just a misdemeanor offense unless you've abused the service to commit some *other* type of felony, but it's still illegal. Aside from that, "illegal" just means "not sanctioned by official rules". Microprocessors and compilers say that instructions are "illegal"; it doesn't mean using them will get you arrested by the state. Clearly, then, doing things that are a violation of the ToS counts as "illegal".

Comment: @CodyGray - That would require a rather egregious break of the ToS which at that point would really have nothing to do with the terms so much as the consequential actions. Illegal generally refers to something breaking criminal law, and while you may argue that it is possible in some scenarios to cross that boundary while violating ToS, having other people use the account would most certainly not qualify.