# About promotional group accounts

Tags: discussion, accounts

I came across this today again after a while ago, and it got me thinking if this kind of conduct is allowed on Stack Overflow. Based on the [recent answer from Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309276/update-the-terms-of-service-to-reflect-the-established-community-consensus-on-sh/309280#309280), it seems that group accounts are still disallowed. Well, this company apparently set up accounts for their individual development teams in an effort to promote themselves:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/9106403/ios-team
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/3497034/dotnet-team
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/4571931/android-team
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/4094161/php-team
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/4571959/java-team

Now, these accounts seem to be making actual legitimate contributions (i.e. not spammy or overly promotional), but from the profile pages it's clear that these aren't individuals, rather shared accounts for the entire development team for a particular technology.

Is this allowed here? If not, what, if anything, should a user do upon noticing such activity? Does Robert's answer on MSE act as official guidance on the matter?

We actually have records of someone spamming for the company that runs those accounts [spamming](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=weblineindia&username=&why=&site=&post_type=&feedback=&autoflagged=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search) in 9 confirmed instances, although that might not be the company itself doing it, so I'm unsure if that matters here.

Comment: Those totally look like the kind of jokers that flood my spam folder with "do you need a web site" garbage every day. I have to admit I wouldn't mind seeing these all nuked, especially given they look like they could use a dodgy votes audit or two

Comment: @Pekka웃 we actually have 10 confirmed spam posts of someone promoting the company on file here: https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=weblineindia&username=&why=&site=&post_type=&feedback=&autoflagged=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search .

Comment: Regarding that last statement ("although that might not be the company itself doing it"), someone did join the Charcoal chatroom back in January and claimed they were not the ones doing the spamming. The conversation starts [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=42080791#42080791). It seems to have taken place during the daily spam wave that rolls through, so it's taking place around SmokeDetector's reports of spam. A shorter version of the request to be removed from SmokeDetector took place on [GitHub](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/issues/1444) and was denied

Comment: This is a related question on Meta.SE: ["Will there be mechanics to handle non-personal profiles?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145899/will-there-be-mechanics-to-handle-non-personal-profiles). I have personally interacted with most of these accounts as a moderator, and I have reason to believe they are all operated by an individual.

Comment: @BradLarson Does that mean that we should flag suspicions of this, but this one in particular doesn't fall under disallowed categories after mod review, or that we should refrain from assuming alltogether?

Comment: @Magisch - I have tended to focus on the behavior of accounts. Are they coordinating questions / answers / votes for one another? Are they dumping bad questions on the site? If they're well-behaved and contributing useful content, I'm less concerned about what they name themselves or put in their profile (as long as it isn't obscene, insulting specific individuals, etc.).

Comment: Having some past experience of having both my experience and, uh, my *cardinality* misrepresented to clients, I'm not sure we can be 100% sure that these "Teams" actually consist of more than one person. And even if they do, we can't be sure that the associated Stack Overflow accounts are controlled by more than one team member. Maybe that shouldn't matter and when somebody claims to be breaking the rules we should take it at face value for enforcement purposes, but as a simple point of fact, I think it's not "clear" at all that these accounts aren't individuals.

Comment: Are you interested in general or just to that specific team? MSFT teams are also present here https://stackoverflow.com/users/7823505/outlook-add-ins-team-msft, but no one bats an eye.

Comment: @BhargavRao Generic, but that was a series of teams I was actually aware of.

Comment: Ah, k. The post seem too targeted towards that particular team, which is why I was a bit concerned.

Comment: @BhargavRao If you'd feel better about it, I can edit out the specific team names and make the question more generic towards teams in general, as there seem to be more then a few. I just never interacted with any other ones besides these. (That I can remember, at least)

Comment: I'm just a bit concerned about linking specific users on meta (as I was from the very beginning). You are well aware of how the meta effect occurs (and we've already started to get flags about just these specific users and no one else). If you ask a generic post, then it'd be a duplicate of [this other meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356923/).  I guess, it's fine to leave it as  it is now, but do take care the next time.

Comment: (Unrelated to my previous comments) There was another case where a group account was used [by a shared team, but that explicitly mentioned that it is operated by multiple individuals](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348522/posting-questions-by-bots). Here, it just mentions as "Team", and it's not quite sure if it's a one person team. (Also there was a lot of irregularities with that account).

Comment: @BhargavRao I didn't really expect a meta effect since I wasn't sure if what they were doing was even considered bad or if I was just misreading a mse post, but I guess I could have foreseen it better, you're right. I'll take more care before posting next time.

Answer (score 38):

The Stack Overflow Public Network Terms of Service states in [point 5: User Obligations](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#obligations) (emphasis mine):

> To access some of the public Network features you will need to **register for an account as an individual** and consent to these Public Network Terms. If you do not consent to these Public Network Terms, Stack Overflow reserves the right to refuse, suspend or terminate your access to the public Network.

That makes it pretty clear to me that team accounts are not allowed. So mod flag one of their posts, and say that this user is a violation of the TOS.

Comment: It doesn't seem as clear to me as it does to you.  I see you've bolded part of that quote.  How do you interpret the part "To access **some** of the public Network features"? (I've added bold to a different part of that quote.)  That makes it sound like there are parts of the site that don't require an individual account.  Which are the parts of the public Network that require an individual account, and which are the parts that don't?

Comment: @D.W. I read it as  “To access some of the public Network features you will need to register for an account (which has to be for an individual rather than a group).”

Comment: @D.W. Correct, the parts that you can access as an anonymous user. "Some" there refers to all the parts of the site restricted to authenticated users.