# Is someone offering to pay for rep-farming on an assigned account allowed?

Tags: discussion, rules, voting-fraud

I'm aware of this probably [similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388810/is-it-ok-to-hire-external-freelancers-to-answer-questions), but I think this has a different flavour.

I came across this "freelance job" [posted on](https://www.upwork.com/freelance-jobs/apply/Answer-Several-Questions-Stack-Overflow_%7E01af8fb1d9714f6029) *[Upwork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upwork)* (emphasis mine):

> Answer several questions on Stack Overflow platform **using an assigned account**, receive upvotes from the answers and **help the account reach reputation points** of 15 in total.

Is it just spam?

Is it next-level sock puppeting?

I consider it a violation of the rules, am I right?

**Notes:**

The suggested dupe:
[Don't be that account: buying and selling reputation and bounties](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410831/dont-be-that-account-buying-and-selling-reputation-and-bounties) is about paying for directly receiving upvotes or bounties. This one is about sharing an account and paying someone else to gain reputation on *that* account. It's related, sure, but I think this is a bit different.

[Can multiple people operate one account?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356923/can-multiple-people-operate-one-account) on the other hand, states

> No, multiple people cannot legally operate a single account.

Which answers the third point.

The job is no longer available, because the freelancer was successfully found. Job stats on Upwork (may not be visible for not logged in users) show "Hired: 1" (in the bottom of screenshot below).

[image: Job posting]

Comment: $35 for only 15 reputation points? That's a steal. Lol! Must be a scam or some kind of bait-and-switch tactic.

Comment: @Ivar That post is what came to my mind initially, but I think there's a difference. This one is about paying for _posting answers_, not for direct upvotes or bounties.

Comment: @Ivar Pretty close. There they were exchanging reputation, here it seems they directly let you use *their* account to gain rep.

Comment: Possibly related: [Can multiple people operate one account?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356923/8967612)

Comment: I've escalated this to CMs. Please raise a flag next time, though

Comment: on any post in general (or, if you believe you've found relevant accounts on Stack, flag any of their posts). Just describe what you've found. Whether the flag is relevant to the question isn't super important with mod flags about problems that go beyond specific posts

Comment: If I had knew that, I would have answered more questions and you would find my account on ebay. :D

Comment: @Bob__ The link is dead, so either SO mods contacted the company to have it removed, or the person who posted the job got wind of this question and removed it.

Comment: @Daedalus Yeah, I'd like the first option. They might have had the job done, though.

Comment: Chances are the reason they specifically want accounts with 15+ reputation is so those accounts have the [upvote privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) - i.e. they want to use those accounts to engage in voting fraud.

Comment: I still see this job, with stats "Activity on the job: Hires: 1". They finally found a freelancer to do this, unfortunately. Link is not dead, this job is shown only to logged in users, probably. @Bob__ would you mind me editing this question to attach a screenshot?

Comment: @SUTerliakov Thanks, please do it.

Comment: It has long been suspected. Now we have some evidence. What is driving it in this case? Spammers? Job applicants who think an online presence is required and buys one (corruption)?

Comment: We should take those jobs whenever they appear.  Post answers, get to 15 rep, get paid.  Then, using your main account, flag/report all those answers and get them deleted.  Dummy account back to zero (or banned), and you have $35 in your pocket.  Poster wouldn't even know it was you that reported them, so you could possibly do this multiple times to the same fraudster.

Comment: @bta That's a good way to go to jail for real life fraud.

Comment: There may be a liquidity problem with reputation points - the offer is $2.33 but the spread is also $2.33.

Comment: @TylerH Not really.  You did what was agreed upon.  It's sort of like leaving your employer, then reporting them for a health and safety violation.  Expecting you to conceal wrongdoing doesn't sound legally tenable.

Comment: @bta No, it's like leaving your employer, and then using a backdoor to delete all the work you did for them. There is nothing illegal about what the job poster is asking for, but entering a contract to provide a service for money and secretly working to undermine said contract after getting paid is _literally_ the definition of fraud.

Answer (score 10):

One individual paying another to answer questions under a 3rd account is not inherently against the rules of the site, although it is definitely a waste of money.

It could *lead* to rule violations very easily if various other conditions or criteria are met, including, but not limited to:

- multiple people operating the same account (although I feel like I see a fair amount of generic 'company support' accounts on here that aren't deleted) -- For what it's worth, the site's Terms & Conditions have changed several times since that 2017 Meta post by Cody Gray; that specific language is not included anymore.
- answering questions asked by another account you have access to in order upvote and accept them
- the job poster re-taking control of the account at a later date
- hiring someone under the age of 13 to operate the account (which might also run afoul of one or more country's labor laws, too)

Comment: it is totally obvious that it leads to these violations so your answer is pointless (sorry to bother you)..

Comment: @kingsjester it's not obvious at all that any of these conditions are necessarily met. Presumably the 3rd one might be, but that's only confirmable if you've spoken with the job poster. Are you the one who took the job?

Comment: i don't see why somebody would be paid to enhance an account which will be used only by him after.. so your first condition is met

Comment: @kingsjester Just because you cannot see it doesn't mean it someone else can't. What's likely and what's true are not always the same.

Comment: How to do it without breaking the account transfer rule: have job poster post answer to question, job taker immediately edit answer to be good answer, and job poster approve edit.

Comment: @Joshua Oh, no... Please, don't suggest loopholes!

Comment: @Bob__: I love posting loopholes that are clear that somebody used them from the history.